# Fetched Properties inside NSFetchedResultsController's predicate

Tags: iphone, core-data, predicates

I have an Artist object with a `.localConcerts` fetched property (basically a subset of the full .`concerts` set), can I use that property inside my NSFetchedResultsController predicate?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Artist" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"localConcerts.@count > 0"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                            initWithFetchRequest:request
                            managedObjectContext:context
                            sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                            cacheName:nil];
```

But I'm getting:

```
'keypath localConcerts not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Artist id=1>'
```

Am I missing anything or is it just not possible to use fetched properties inside predicates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently `NSPredicate` can only filter using attributes that are in the database structure (this makes sense). In my case, using a subquery did the trick:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(shows, $show, $show.distance < %@).@count > 0", [SWDataManager sharedManager].localFilterDistance];
```

I had no idea we could do [subqueries in NSPredicate](http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2726166818/what-the-heck-is-subquery), that's great to know. Credits go to [@kyleve](http://twitter.com/kyleve).