# Using a NSFetchedResultsController with an NSManagedObject and fetched properties

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a database of `Card`s and `Printing`s that I have in one store (reference data) and my user's data of `Container`s and `CardInstance`s in another store (as Apple suggests).  Each user's card is a table `CardInstance` that contains a specific `printingID` that corresponds with a specific printing of a card.  I'm trying to use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to filter the values of the cards so that it can manage the groupings and stuff using reusable code.

Again, here's the basic overview of the tables:
`Card` (which has `nameNormalized` and `alphaNormalized` and `typeNormalized` properties that I want to filter and group on in the Fetched Results Controller).
`Printing` (which has a `card` relationship and a specific `printingID`)
`CardInstance` (which has a `container` relationship, a `printingID` property, and a `printingFetch` fetched property on `Printing` with predicate: `printingID = $FETCH_SOURCE.printingID`).
`Container` (which has a to-many relationship of `CardInstance`s).

Given a `Container`, I'm wanting to use a NSFetchedResultsController so that I can change the sort and groupings between name and type sections.  So I have a fetchRequest where I've set the entity type to `CardInstance` and one predicate to `container = %@`, the given container.

1) How do I set the sort descriptors so that I can sort on `printingFetch.card.nameNormalized` or on `printingFetch.card.typeNormalized`?

2) How do I filter the results if I want to find all cards containing the word @"the"?  I was thinking something along the lines of `printingFetch.card.nameNormalized contains %@`, @"the", but that just results in a crash.

I realize I could do this all manually, but if the container ends up containing a lot of cards, that may be way too slow and I'd like to not have to re-write the sectioning and grouping code that `NSFetchedResultsController` should automatically do for me.

Comment: Why are these entities reside in different stores? apple specifically mentioned that it is not possible to create relationships across stores (only maintain them manually).

Comment: Because the cards and printings are cached/generated reference data and the card instances and collections are user data.  Apple specifically says to do this and not keep recreatable data in the user store.